# Why are some tags different colours?

Tags: discussion, tags

In [this question](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2722/why-is-editing-tags-not-considered-an-edit), there is a bold white tag, [bug], a red one, [status-norepro] and two grey ones.

Similarly, in [this one](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/when-is-the-next-moderator-election), there is a white, red and grey tag.

What do these colours mean, is it to do with the popularity of the tag, or are white ones general topics, and red ones sub-topics etc...?

*PS: all meta tags must have a 'white' tag - does this mean they are more important, indicating that they are general topics?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Legend is at the bottom of [this](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/tags) page.

Red = moderator only

Bold White = required

Grey = normal tag

Comment: Ah, thanks, stupid me :P